# PHP Order by last name with middlename

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a database field called `last_name`.
I want to order the list by last name.

Here is an example:
**Name**
Jan DSmit
Jan van de WSmit
Jan van ASmit
Jan de FSmit

I tried doing this with SUBSTRING INDEX but that only searches a space. I have multiple.
 
I have a query that orders the last name field like this

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, meta_value as name 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key 
          LIKE 'last_name' 
          AND user_id 
          IN (SELECT user_id 
              FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
              WHERE meta_key='company' 
              AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded_brands."')) 
              ORDER BY name";
```

`$implode_brands` holds an array of brandnames.
This works but when the ordering kicks in it places all the people who start with 'van' or 'de' next to eachother like the script tells it to do. I would like to order at the name behind the 'van' and 'de'.

The expected result should be:
**Name**
Jan van ASmit
Jan DSmit
Jan de FSmit
Jan van de WSmit

---- EDIT----
After some reading I found: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919441/mysql-order-by-last-name-when-full-name-for-column) and [this](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)

After applying it didn't work but maybe I'm doing something wrong here

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, meta_value as name 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key 
          LIKE 'last_name' 
          AND user_id 
          IN (
             SELECT user_id 
             FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
             WHERE meta_key='company' 
             AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded_brands."')) 
             ORDER BY REPLACE (REPLACE (last_name, ' van ', ' '), ' de ', ' ')";
```

Comment: Please give good examples of what you want the ordering to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal if I got it correctly has no sense to me.

But just in case you really need that try:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, meta_value as name 
          FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE meta_key 
          LIKE 'last_name' 
          AND user_id 
          IN (SELECT user_id 
              FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
              WHERE meta_key='company' 
              AND meta_value IN ('".$imploded_brands."')) 
          ORDER BY REPLACE (REPLACE (name, ' van ', ' '), ' de ', ' ')";
```

You can try replace last line in query to:

```
ORDER BY REPLACE (REPLACE (last_name, ' van ', ' '), ' de ', ' ')";
```

Comment: No luck. The idea is that the ordering comes directly from the query and not afterwards in the PHP

Comment: there is no php condition in my answer. it is SQL order and it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1e4f/3

Comment: It's not that I want to argue or disagree with you but it really isn't working. The names are still sorted upon the middlenames. Please see the query I use after the EDIT part.

Comment: Provide sample of data tables and expected result. The best is to create sql fiddle as I did. my query and order is simple and working. so just provide sample of your data to discuss more.

Comment: I owe you a very very deep and shameful apologie. I have another list on another page that needs to be sorted on exatly the same way. I was changing it in one file and uploading the other! It works, like you said, perfect. Thank you

Comment: Yeah well, I think that I'll go to bed first :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion it would be better to sort the resulting array in php and not sort the data directly from the query. So something like this should work:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  $a = str_replace("van", "", $a);
  $a = str_replace("de", "",$a);
  $b = str_replace("van", "", $b);
  $b = str_replace("de", "",$b);
  return strnatcmp($a, $b);
}

usort($result_without_order, 'cmp');
```

Not tested but i assume it should work fine and give you the expected results.